# Download artifacts using REST from Team City

Tags: rest, powershell, teamcity, powershell-4.0

Using Team City 2017.1.1 (build 46654) I am trying to download artifacts using REST from Powershell on windows 10.

I am using this:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildArtifacts

but I still cannot get it to work. As an example I am trying download the info.txt artifact that I can access using my browser from the below URL:

```
http://mytc/repository/download/MyBuildConfiguration/294859:id/output/logs/info.txt
```

Based on:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildArtifacts

I am doing the following from Powershell:

```
$TeamCityUser = 'tcuser'
$TeamCityPassword = 'tcpass'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $TeamCityPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($TeamCityUser, $securePassword)

$response = Invoke-WebRequest http://mytc/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/294859:id/artifacts/output/logs/info.txt -Credential $creds
```

But I get the error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Based on below suggestion I have now tried:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest http://mytc/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:294859/artifacts/output/logs/info.txt -Credential $creds
```

But still get:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242139/how-do-i-download-a-protected-file-using-powershell) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate recursively the artifacts of a given build:

http://mytc/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:294859/artifacts/
And use the node: `children` of the response.

Response might be:

```
<files count="1">
    <file name="output" modificationTime="20170724T160034+0200" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:294859/artifacts/metadata/output">
        <children href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:294859/artifacts/children/output"/>
    </file>
</files>
```

Then, making the same request on: `children.href`, you may have another child. (ie: logs)
When you reach the leaf item you want, instead of the children node, you will have a content node with the href you want to call.

```
<files count="1">
    <file name="info.txt" size="75435" modificationTime="20170724T160034+0200" href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:3906258/artifacts/metadata/output/logs/info.txt">
        <content href="/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:3906258/artifacts/content/output/logs/info.txt"/>
    </file>
</files>
```

Using the responses recursively will ensure the path of the artefact is correct, and the case. And will ensure the artefact is still available.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you need to change ID format and add /content/ in URL, replace

> http://mytc/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/294859:id/artifacts/output/logs/info.txt

with

> http://mytc/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:294859/artifacts/content/output/logs/info.txt

Comment: I used the following URL

https://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:6590/artifacts/content/jar/arm.jar

where jar/arm.jar is the artifact path

you should also add '/content/' to url